En C++, ¿por qué una sentencia que fue definida luego de la función main se ejecuta correctamente?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcion1();

int main()
{
  funcion1();    
  return 0;
}

int var = 5;

void funcion1()
{
  cout << " 'var' tiene 
  el valor: " <<  var << '\n';
}

Al ejecutar el programa la sentencia int var = 5 se ejecuta. Pero ¿por qué esto es posible? ¿Cuál es el orden de ejecución del programa? ¿No tendría que haber pasado por alto el compilador a la anterior sentencia citada dada su posición en el programa?

Es una variable que esta fuera de la función, por lo tanto es tomada como una variable global y por ende se setean antes que las funciones.

Da para una explicacion mucho mas larga, pero no confundas un lenguaje compilado (como c++) con un lenguaje de scipting (como python)... aca se compila todo el programa, y no importa necesariamente el orden de aparicion de algunas cosas para que estas sean tomadas en cuenta por el compilador.. porque pensas que no deberia ejecutarse eso?

Muchas gracias. Es que pensaba que primero se ejecutaban las sentencias antes de main, después main con la llamada a la función, y por último la función.

@Martín Hola, podrias decirnos si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que mas util te haya resultado, si lo deseas tambien puedes darle un voto positivo a las respuestas que consideres correctas, gracias

Me han sido todas útiles. Gracias.

@Martín para marcar una respuesta como aceptada debes dar clic sobre el checkmark que sale al lado de la respuesta, justo arriba de las flechas de votación, solo puedes marcar una respuesta dada a tu publicación como aceptada, pero puedes votar positivo todas las respuestas que desees en tu publicación, marcar una respuesta como aceptada le otorga 15 ptos a quien responde, votar positivo otorga 10 ptos a quien responde, y además marcar la respuesta como aceptada te otorga a ti 2 ptos, mientras más ptos tengas más prestigio y privilegios de moderación tendrás en la comunidad

@Martín para entender mejor como funciona el mecanismo de votación y aceptación de respuesta puedes revisar el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

No es impedimento que la variable se encuentre luego de la función main para que exista. La función main no sabe que la variable existe porque fue declarada después.

Encontré algo interesante https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization?view=msvc-170

Parece que no tuviste la oportunidad de aprender el concepto de ámbito (scope en inglés), te voy a pegar un extracto del estándar del lenguaje C++ que hace referencia a dicho concepto (traducción y resaltado míos):

6.4 (Ámbito) Scope
6.4.1 General
Las declaraciones de un programa aparecen en múltiples ámbitos que en general no son contiguos. El ámbito global contiene el programa al completo; cualquier otro ámbito A se introduce mediante una declaración […]

Es decir, toda declaración aparece en un ámbito siendo el más grande el ámbito general, por ejemplo este programa:
int f()
{
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
}

struct P { int x, y; };

float f = 0.f;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = f();
    int b = f();

    auto lambda = [c = a, d = b] { return c + d; };

    P p{lambda(), lambda()};

    return 0;
}

Tiene el siguiente aspecto a nivel de ámbitos:

Ámbito global
int f();

struct P;

float f;

int main(int, char);


Ámbito f
static int i;




Ámbito main
int argc;

char **argv;

int a;

int b;

auto lambda;

P p;



Ámbito lambda
auto c;

auto d;




Ámbito p
int x;

int y;






 
Todos los ámbitos se comportan de la misma manera excepto el ámbito global, que tiene las siguientes características:

Contiene todos los demás ámbitos.
Existe siempre, sin necesidad de haber sido declarado.
Sólo puede contener declaraciones o definiciones:
// ambito 'global'
int i = 0;
i = i + 1; // Error, esto es una expresión.

void f()
{
     // ambito 'f'
     int i = 0;
     i = i + 1; // Correcto.
}


Sus datos son accesibles mediante el operador de ámbito (::) (aunque estén ensombrecidos):
int i = 100;

void f()
{
     int i = 42;
     std::cout << i << ' ' << ::i << '\n'; // muestra 42 100

     {
         int i = 20;
         std::cout << i << ' ' << ::i << '\n'; // muestra 20 100
     }
}

int main()
{
     f();
}


Sus variables se inicializan implícitamente a cero, mientras que en el resto de ámbitos sólo se inicializan explícitamente:
int i;

int main()
{
     int i;
     if (i == 0)
         std::cout << "Hola\n"; // No se muestra.
     if (::i == 0)
         std::cout << "Mundo\n"; // Se muestra.
}




Todas las instrucciones hacen algo, pero no necesariamente en tiempo de ejecución. Muchas solo se usan al momento de compilar el programa.
Por ejemplo, las declaraciones de clases, estructuras o funciones no hacen nada por sí solas a la hora de ejecutar el programa. De nada sirve declarar una clase o una función que no vas a usar.
Según la documentación, las variables globales se inicializan al comienzo del programa, antes de que la ejecución de la función main comience.
En el ámbito global solo están permitidas las declaraciones (de variables, funciones y clases, entre otras). Las otras sentencias no. Por ejemplo, si pusieras un if fuera de cualquier función el código no compilaría.

Muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo mucho, me gusta mucho este foro.

La variable var es global, lo cual quiere decir que será accesible desde cualquier parte del programa y se inicializará automáticamente al comenzar la ejecución del programa, antes de entrar a la función main. Por eso, aunque la declaración de var aparece después de la función main en el código, ya está disponible y con su valor asignado cuando se llama a funcion1.
Las variables globales se definen fuera del cuerpo de cualquier función, generalmente al principio del programa, después de la definición de los archivos de biblioteca (#include), de la definición de constantes simbólicas y antes de cualquier función.
Como nota final te digo que en este mundo de la programación todo tiene pros y contras, y las variables globales no escapan a esto, y se debe ser cuidadoso en su uso, ya que pueden romper con el principio de la modularidad y el bajo acoplamiento.

Muchas gracias, me has aclarado la duda totalmente.

esta respuesta no es correcta porque en c++ las variables deben ser declaradas antes de ser usadas, un compilador que siga el estandar nunca va hacer hoisting de variables. La razon por la que el codigo funciona es simple, el compilador puede compilar function1 porque var esta declarada antes de su implementacion y la declaracion de funtion1 esta antes de la implementacion de main por lo que el compilador no tiene problema al hacer reference a function1.

@clay yo puedo equivocarme pero me parece que el error es tuyo, var es global y se carga antes de entrar al metodo main, y es desde este metodo main que se invoca a funcion1

No, eso que tu dices se llama hoisting de variables y no es un comportamiento del compilador de c++ . Lo mas simple: haste un hola mundo y declara una variable debajo del main y trata de usarlar dicha variable dentro del main. Cuando compiles te va a dar error.

La siguiente explicación tiene como objetivo ser lo más simple posible para que cualquier persona pueda entender hasta cierto punto los conceptos mencionados en ella.
Los lenguajes se pueden clasificar de dos formas.
Los lenguajes "compilados" e "interpretados".
Lenguajes compilados
Los lenguajes compilados "Analizan el código que escribiste y hacen una serie de verificaciones antes traducirlo a código binario (código máquina)."
Los lenguajes compilados son mucho más rápidos que los lenguajes interpretados, puesto que ya te dan el código ejecutable y la máquina solo debe ejecutar el código
Es más difícil detectar error sintáctico en los programas hechos con ellos.
No es tan importante como en los compilados el orden del programa a diferencia de los interpretados.
Lenguajes Interpretados
Los lenguajes interpretados "Analizan y traducen el código en tiempo de ejecución."
Son más lentos debido a que están analizando y traduciendo código para que la máquina lo ejecute.
Es raro que haya un error sintáctico puesto que se ejecutan línea por línea.
Es importante que haya un orden muy claro en las instrucciones por cada línea.
Ejemplos de ejecución.
Lenguajes interpretados
función hola ( a ) { imprimir a }
hola ( "Hola Mundo" )

Lenguajes compilados
función hola (a);
hola ("Hola Mundo");
función hola (a) { imprimir a }

Comparación del código
En los interpretados es imposible declarar una función después sin antes definir lo que hace, así que se debe definir en el momento y trae como desventaja una menor organización de código.
En los lenguajes compilados puedes declarar funciones y luego darles una definición; O puedes declarar funciones en un archivo y en otro  darles una definición.
Dependiendo del lenguaje compilado, se puede requerir obligatoriamente una definición antes de compilar; en algunos otros basta con solo declararla bien para poder compilar.
Ejemplo explícito de tu código
Este es tu código.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcion1();

int main()
{
  funcion1();    
  return 0;
}

int var = 5;

void funcion1()
{
  cout << " 'var' tiene 
  el valor: " <<  var << '\n';
}

¿No crees que es poco claro con lo que hace?
Pues al usar el compilador, lo que hace es eliminar lo innecesario.
Elimina está línea void funcion1(); porque es innecesaria en el contexto de tu código.
Cada programa y código compilado tiene su contexto, así que varia mucho el código binario generado.
Esto de aquí es tu código de forma explícita (casi binario), en pseudo código ensamblador; el lenguaje ensamblador es un lenguaje de programación, que cada parte del código en él, es equivalente a una instrucción en código binario (código máquina).
No es necesario que entiendas que dice el código, sino que así se ve tu código cuando es traducido a código binario (código máquina).
var equ 5 ; Pensamos cuanto vale var 'int var = 5'

funcion1: ; Inicio de la función
syscall ; Llamamos al sistema y le decimos que nos cae bien
call imprimir " 'var' tiene el valor: ", [var] ; Le decimos al sistema que le diga a su hermana el mensaje y que el valor de var es 5
ret ; Final de la función

main: ; La hermana del sistema
call funcion1 ; El sistema transmite el mensaje y enamoramos a su hermana
ret ; Le decimos al sistema que le mentimos, nos cae mal y que ya no lo necesitamos ahora que salimos con su hermana. Enojado se va, volviendo a hacer sus cosas.
; En otras palabras en "ret" termina el programa

Eso es lo que hace tu compilador, elimina lo innecesario y deja solo lo relevante, es algo que no hacen los lenguajes interpretados.

void funcion1() no se puede quitar ya que es la declaracion de la funcion y siempre debe ir cuando la implementacion va despues de la llamada a la funcion (en este caso la llamada a la funcion esta en main y la implementacion debajo de main). Sin la declaracion se lanzaria un error en tiempo de compilacion.

Yo dije algunos compiladores no necesitan una definición puesto que pueden generar una función  función: ret en código máquina y se puede ver en ensamblador. @clay

También dije que una declaración previa no es necesaria si se define al mismo tiempo que se declara. @clay

Muchas gracias a los dos, me lo habéis aclarado totalmente.
